# Example of Swagger Configuration with Security in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

Someone has an example of swagger security with spring boot?

My docket config it is like this:

```
@Bean
public Docket userApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .select()
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
    .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
    .build()
    .apiInfo(metaData());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to configure swagger with security you should set the securityContexts like this :

```
private final TypeResolver typeResolver;

// constructor
public SwaggerConfig(TypeResolver typeResolver) {
    this.typeResolver = typeResolver;
}
@Bean
public Docket apiBatch() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("path.to.package"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()))
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title(title)
            .description(description)
            .version(version)
            .build();
}

/**
 * add as header the Authorization header
 *
 * @return
 */
private ApiKey apiKey() {
    return new ApiKey("apiKey", "Authorization", "header");
}

/**
 * demand the authorization for access on /api/v1/**
 *
 * @return
 */
private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/v1.*")).build();
}

private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(
            "global", "accessEverything");
    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
    authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
    return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("apiKey",
            authorizationScopes));
}

private AlternateTypeRule getAlternateTypeRule(Type sourceType, Type sourceGenericType,
                                               Type targetType, Type targetGenericType) {
    return AlternateTypeRules.newRule(typeResolver.resolve(sourceType, sourceGenericType),
            typeResolver.resolve(targetType, targetGenericType));
}
```

### Edit

I've added the TypeResolver property of fasterxml classmate library ( `compile group: 'com.fasterxml', name: 'classmate', version: '1.3.1'` )

**Note** that `SwaggerConfig` is the config class name

Comment: Yes ! you need to add a property of type TypeResolver and use constructor autowiring ( you can see my update above)

Comment: and the Type class?

Comment: when you create the getAlternateTypeRule function, you use "Type sourceType" but what import Type is?

Comment: Ah sorry it's from java.lang.reflect

Comment: @Abdelhani Roussi, do you have an email that i can contact you?

Comment: @A.Carlos yes roussi.abdelghani@gmail.com feel free to contact me !